# How can I apply a transformation to a torch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, transform, interpolation, torchvision

I have a Torch Tensor `z` and I would like to apply a transformation matrix `mat` to `z` and have the output be exactly the same size as `z`. Here is the code I am running:

```
def trans(z):
    print(z)
    mat = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),transforms.RandomRotation(90),transforms.ToTensor()])
    z = Variable(mat(z.cpu()).cuda())
    z = nnf.interpolate(z, size=(28, 28), mode='linear', align_corners=False)
    return z
z = trans(z)
```

However, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e2fc36889ba5> in <module>()
      3 inputs,targs=next(iter(tst_loader))
      4 recon, mean, var = vae.predict(model, inputs[img_idx])
----> 5 out = vae.generate(model, mean, var)

4 frames
/content/vae.py in generate(model, mean, var)
     90     z = trans(z)
     91     z = Variable(z.cpu().cuda())
---> 92     out = model.decode(z)
     93     return out.data.cpu()
     94 

/content/vae.py in decode(self, z)
     56 
     57     def decode(self, z):
---> 58         out = self.z_develop(z)
     59         out = out.view(z.size(0), 64, self.z_dim, self.z_dim)
     60         out = self.decoder(out)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     89 
     90     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 91         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     92 
     93     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1674         ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
   1675     else:
-> 1676         output = input.matmul(weight.t())
   1677         if bias is not None:
   1678             output += bias

RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0
```

How can I successfully apply this rotation transform `mat` and not get any errors doing so?

Thanks,
Vinny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `interpolate` expects a batch dimension, and looks like your data does not have one, based on the error message and the successful application of `transforms`. Since your input is spatial (based on the `size=(28, 28)`), you can fix that by adding the batch dimension and changing the `mode`, since `linear` is [not implemented](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/671160a96327e95f74734e6cc6b676bee3080f33/torch/nn/functional.py#L3167-L3172) for spatial input:

```py
z = nnf.interpolate(z.unsqueeze(0), size=(28, 28), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
```

If you want `z` to still have a shape like (C, H, W), then:

```py
z = nnf.interpolate(z.unsqueeze(0), size=(28, 28), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False).squeeze(0)
```

Comment: I tried this out and I got this error: ```NotImplementedError: Got 4D input, but linear mode needs 3D input``` Any idea why this is happening @Berriel?

Comment: @VinnyJacobsen oh, that's true... `linear` upsample does not work with spatial input. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: this takes me back to the initial error: `RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0` @Berriel

Comment: @VinnyJacobsen this is not the initial error... please, update the question with `z.shape` right before the `interpolate` call

Comment: @VinnyJacobsen as you can see, the error is happening somewhere else... so there original problem has been solved. And that is probably not the full stacktrace either.

Comment: Yes I will accept your answer, but I would appreciate your help on this new error. The full stacktrace is provided in the question, please check that out. @Berriel

Comment: @VinnyJacobsen sure. As this is a new problem, following SO guidelines, open a new question and link it here so that I know. Also, on your new question, provide the `z.shape` before this line: `out = model.decode(z)`

Comment: Alright @Berriel, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770296/how-can-i-apply-transform-mat-to-torch-tensor

Comment: would appreciate your help on the other problem, link is in my above comment. @Berriel